# Is choosing smaller-than-architecture size variables a valid choice?

Tags: c

I need some advice.

Situation:

- I'm developing an ANSI C application on an 32 bit architecture.
- Most variables of my business logic fit into uint8_t by design.
- Most variables have to be send in messages as uint8_t data segments
- I do not use struct packing

Questions:

- Would my application profit in terms of portability if i would use size_t and downcast all variables on the external interface serialization?
- Are there performance effects using uint8_t or size_t+casting beside the serialization part?
- Is there a best practice regarding choice of variable size for smaller-than-architecture size variables?

Kind regards

Comment: Write your code so that it's clear what you mean for people who'll maintain it in the future. If the data in the business logic will always fit in uint8_t, then use uint8_t. It's clearer and reduces mental load when trying to decode what the code does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is choosing smaller-than-architecture size variables a valid choice?

Yes.  Use selectively.

> Would my application profit in terms of portability if i would use `size_t` and downcast all variables on the external interface serialization?

No. Use `size_t` to index arrays and size calculations, not general integer math.  Its range varies by platform.

> Are there performance effects using `uint8_t` or `size_t` +casting beside the  serialization part?

Avoid casting unless needed.  Using `uint8_t` has a significant plus in that there is no byte endian issue.  Other specific performance serialization issues exist for the unposted code, yet need to see that.

> Is there a best practice regarding choice of variable size for smaller-than-architecture size variables?

For *arrays* of data, using the smallest type that encodes the entire range needed is good.

For reading/writing binary files, use explicit types such a `uint8_t, int32_t` that match the file format.

For explicit algorithms that oblige a specific width type, use `uint8_t, int16_t, etc.`

Else, coding for clarity is the major concern.  [@Art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190910/is-choosing-smaller-than-architecture-size-variables-a-valid-choice/45193376#comment77349266_45190910)

---

Using smaller than `int/unsigned` brings in unexpected and often subtle promotions/math effects.  There are best avoided and used when there is 1) a requirement 2) *significant* space concern.

`int/unsigned` tend to be the optimal type for a platforms speed.  Use `fast` types [@Lanting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192460/2410359) for select critical code.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, `size_t` would be a bad choice to store some data that would fit into 8 bits. There are platforms where `size_t` is larger than the machine's *natural word size*.

In the general case, I would recommend to use (`unsigned`)`int`. Although this is not guaranteed, most of the time you will get the best performance this way. It could be a bad choice on an 8bit µc for example, because `int` must have at least 16 bits. But in the general case, it's a good choice.

If your concern is memory consumption (e.g. you have huge arrays of data, but all single values would fit into an `uint8_t`), **then** you should use `uint8_t` instead.

Of course it's not possible to give a **definitive** answer here. If you decide to use `unsigned int`, but have to (de-)serialize very often, this could cost you more than just using `uint8_t` throughout the entire program. If in doubt, try both implementations (using `typedef`s and conditional compilation) and *measure* performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Would my application profit in terms of portability if i would use 
>   size_t and downcast all variables on the external interface serialization?

Both uint8_t and size_t are portable, just use them correctly. If you store a value that will never exceed 8 bits, independetly of the architecture, you can safely use uint8_t. It is guaranteed that it will have the same size on all architectures that support it.

size_t is guaranteed to be be large enough to hold the size of any object. If you need that functionality, then use size_t. However, you cannot make assumptions about size_t's actual size, other than it being at least 16bit.

> Are there performance effects using uint8_t or size_t+casting beside
>   the serialization part?

The choice of algorithms and good data structures impacts performance, don't worry about the choice of integer types. As this is also dependent on the compiler, the architecure, even the processor, there cannot be a final answer. Make some benchmarks if you are really curious, but I say you won't see any differences.

> Is there a best practice regarding choice of variable size for
>   smaller-than-architecture size variables?

Yes and no. How would you mesure code quality? Portability, readability, performance, memory needs, ... Everything is dependent on your use case. Best practise for writing portable code is using portable types and not making any assumptions. Comment your code. For some special embedded use cases it might be good to use small types whenever possible to save memory. But again, there cannot be a general answer.

Comment: Detail: "Both uint8_t and size_t are portable" --> `uint8_t` is pseudo-optional.  Required on all that can support it (most platforms), but it is not required and does not exist on the remaining few.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the [fast types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) yet.

`int_fast8_t`n `uint_fast8_t` `int_fast16_t` etc. provide integer type definitions that are at least as fast as any other integer type on the target with at least the specified width.

Comment: I was about to mention them, so the upvote... But you should add that they aim to improve perfs at a possible cost in used memory.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the answers to your questions respectively:

- It will not profit, but it will increase the complexity of the code.
- There will be performance effect, but it will be in terms of few machine cycles. You should care for that if you are really writing very much time critical programs like Avionics.
- There is no such best practice for using variable size as per architecture of the CPU. Programs should be designed with the portability in mind rather than CPU specific.

I hope this helps.